# How to determine statistical significance in shell

Tags: shell, unix, awk, statistics, gnuplot

I would like to determine the statistical significance of my results using shell scripting. My input file shows the number of errors in each trial in 10000 observations. Part of it is listed as: (using a threshold of having at least 1 error)

```
ifile.txt
1
2
2
4
1
3
2
3
4
2
3
4
2
6
2
```

Then I calculated the probability of each numbered error, which I calculated as:

```
awk '{ count[$0]++; total++ } 
END { for(i in count) printf("%d %.3f\n", i, count[i]/total) }' ifile.txt | sort -n > ofile.txt
```

where first column in ofile.txt shows the number of errors and 2nd column shows its probability

```
ofile.txt
1 0.133
2 0.400
3 0.200
4 0.200
6 0.067
```

Now I need to determine the statistical significance of this result e.g. to highlight those results which are not statistically significant at 1% level. i.e. we will accept those errors which are having p-value < 0.005 and if a error has p-value > 0.005 then we will reject it.

I can't think of any method to do this in shell. Can anybody help/suggest me something?

Desire output is something like:

```
outfile.txt
1 99999  
2 0.400
3 0.200
4 0.200
6 99999
```

Here, I assumed the probability of showing 1 error is not statistically significent at 1% level, but the probability of showing 2 errors is statistically significant and so on.

Comment: How do you define "statistical significance"? Is this the values that are above a given threshold? Please provide some explanation of this, together with the expected output for your given input.

Comment: @fedorqui Thank you very much for your response. I would like to define it as to accept the errors having p-value < 0.005. So if a error has p-value > 0.005 then it is rejected. Yes, I have used a threshold of having at least 1 error. The trials with no error are excluded from the analysis. I am sorry that I can't understand the expected outcomes.

Comment: What I mean is that you should [edit] your question and show how would you like the output to be.

Comment: @fedorqui .. As suggested, I modified the question and waiting for some help/suggestion.. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `9999` in your desired output and not `99999` or do you mean `100000` observations and not `10000`?

Comment: I am afraid it is still unclear. You should try to explain in words what the algorithm should do, now what the theory says. I know about `p-value` in general, but not how you are using it here.

Answer (score 0):

With no statistics education or gnuplot experience, it's a bit difficult to decipher exactly the desired methods for a solution.  The problem may not be described well enough or my knowledge is ill-equipped for it.

Either way, after looking at the relationships between the data presented and desired output, I came up with this Awk script to achieve it:

```
$ cat script.awk
function abs(v) { return v < 0 ? -v : v }
{ a[$0]++ }
END {
    obs = 10000
    sig = 1
    for (i in a) {
        r = a[i]/NR
        if (abs(r-sig/10) <= sig/20)
            print i, obs-sig
        else
            printf "%d %.3f\n", i, r
    }
}
$ awk -f script.awk ifile.txt | sort > outfile.txt
$ cat outfile.txt 
1 9999
2 0.400
3 0.200
4 0.200
6 9999
```

This assumes `9999` (10000 (number of observations) - 1 (error)) was meant as the second field in the 1st and 5th lines in the desired output, not `99999`.

Also, if using GNU Awk, the need for a pipe into `sort` could be eliminated by using the [sort function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Array-Sorting-Functions.html#Array-Sorting-Functions) `asorti`.